# Login required on one github project but not others

Tags: github

I AM ABLE to push to my other projects on git w/o requiring login.

However on a new private project, I am now required to enter username/password. I verified my keys.

Interesting that I run `ssh -vv LarryEitel@github.com` and after verbose log, it returns permission denied.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably cloned this specific repository using the https:// URL instead of the ssh URL given on GitHub homepage. You can check that by taking a look at the .git/config file.

Also, to test ssh connection, you should do:

```
ssh -vv git@github.com
```

Access is provided by your public ssh key stored on GitHub and not by your user ID.

Comment: That was brilliant. All I had to do to fix it was to edit .git/config and 
change:
  url = https://     github.com/LarryEitel/ofm.git
to:
  url = git@    github.com:LarryEitel/ofm.git

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @LarryEitel I'm glad I could help you. In that case, don't forget to accept the answer so that everyone can see this question is solved.